# Why is the list length changing every time I run this loop, in Python, to only store even numbers?

Tags: python, loops

I'm thoroughly confused by this one. I'm running a FOR loop that identifies all even numbers (modular division) and stores them.

However, every time I run the loop on the same list of numbers, the list length **decreases**? I don't really understand this, as surely all those numbers should be removed on the first time running the loop?

I've copied the code below.

```
# Sanity check - Modular [remainder] divison in loops

# Python Libraries 
from random import randint

# Create a list of 50 random integers between 0 and 1000
randomNumbers = []
for i in range(100): 
    randomInt = randint(0, 1000) 
    randomNumbers.append(randomInt)
print("List of 50 values: ", randomNumbers,"\n") 

# Remove odd numbers
counter     = 0

for i in randomNumbers: 
    if(i % 2 != 0):
        randomNumbers.remove(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(randomNumbers)))

for i in randomNumbers: 
    if(i % 2 != 0):
        randomNumbers.remove(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(randomNumbers)))

for i in randomNumbers: 
    if(i % 2 != 0):
        randomNumbers.remove(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(randomNumbers)))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Realised the first upload was the wrong (both file AND structure AND just everything) code, this should be the correct version now.

Comment: why iterating random numbers 3 times to check the even number and  appending them i list again and again

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are **re-appending the even numbers** in the list. What does that mean?

```
foo = []
for i in range(1, 7):
    foo.append(i)
for i in range(1, 7):
    foo.append(i)
# foo == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Hope that helps illustrate what's happening.
Try removing the append second and third time. Code will be:

```
# Sanity check - Modular [remainder] divison in loops

# Python Libraries 
from random import randint

# Create a list of 50 random integers between 0 and 1000
randomNumbers = []
for i in range(100): 
    randomInt = randint(0, 1000) 
    randomNumbers.append(randomInt)
print("List of 50 values: ", randomNumbers,"\n") 

# Remove odd numbers
evenNumbers = []
counter     = 0

for i in range(len(randomNumbers)): 
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        evenNumbers.append(i)
        counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(evenNumbers)))

for i in range(len(randomNumbers)): 
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(evenNumbers)))

for i in range(len(randomNumbers)): 
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(evenNumbers)))
```

I replaced it with range but you can use the method you were using that works too.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same list again and again and......again    :)

```
# Sanity check - Modular [remainder] divison in loops

# Python Libraries 
from random import randint

# Create a list of 50 random integers between 0 and 1000
randomNumbers = []
for i in range(100): 
    randomInt = randint(0, 1000) 
    randomNumbers.append(randomInt)
print("List of 50 values: ", randomNumbers,"\n") 

# Remove odd numbers
evenNumbers = []
counter     = 0

for i in randomNumbers: 
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        evenNumbers.append(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(evenNumbers)))

# RESET THE LIST
evenNumbers = []

for i in randomNumbers: 
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        evenNumbers.append(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(evenNumbers)))

# RESET THE LIST
evenNumbers = []

for i in randomNumbers: 
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        evenNumbers.append(i)
counter += 1
print("Loop run: "+str(counter))
print('\t > List length = '+str(len(evenNumbers)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The array `evenNumbers` is in the global scope and therefore remains in memory after each loop.
The values accumulate, and therefore you see a doubling of the length after the second loop and a tripling after the third loop.

For more information on the scoping of variables in Python, you can visit see this [W3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) or read the [language documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/executionmodel.html).

Answer (score 0):

The other guys seem to have answered your question pretty well, so I came up with a simpler alternate solution that does not require a for loop to remove odd numbers. You can use the filter function to do what you want.

```
from random import randint

rand_nums = []
for _ in range(100):  # if you are using 100 as the range, it will create a list with length 100
    rand_int = randint(0, 1000)
    rand_nums.append(rand_int)
print(f"List of {len(rand_nums)} values: {rand_nums}")

# Remove odd numbers
evens_only = list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, rand_nums))
print(f"List of even values only: {evens_only}\nLength of even list: {len(evens_only)}")
```

Here is another way you could do it using list comprehension:

```
from random import randint
rand_nums = [randint(0, 1000) for j in range(100)]
print(f"List of {len(rand_nums)} values: {rand_nums}")
evens_only = [i for i in rand_nums if i % 2 == 0]
print(f"List of even values only: {evens_only}\nLength of even list: {len(evens_only)}")
```